# Count previous 24 months rows based on condition from current row

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to count the previous 24 months from a current row based on principalreliefflag(It should be based on each row (each month with previous  24 months). So count principal flag(Y) from current row to previous 24 months.)?

Data I have:

[image]

Data I need:

[image]

Code:

```
       -------------------------------------------------------------------------
----Identify customers who are on principal relief more than one month
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##PRappliedmorethan_once') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##PRappliedmorethan_once
select *,
case when  PrincipalReliefFlag='Y'  then 1 else 0
                                      end  PR_applied_months

 into ##PRappliedmorethan_once
 from ##TL_details_dates2 



 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##PRappliedmorethan_once1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##PRappliedmorethan_once1
select *,
--Identify customers who have applied for principal relief within the past 12 months



sum(PR_applied_months) over    (partition by productitemcode, productcode
                                      order by dim_snapshotdate_key
                                      rows between  23 preceding and current row
                                     )
                                      abcd





 into ##PRappliedmorethan_once1
 from ##PRappliedmorethan_once
```

It works but is there any better way?

Comment: Ramu, looking at what you want, snapshotdate 20180831, because the flag = 'N', PRinlast124months equals the value of last PRinlast124months with the flag = 'Y'. However that behaviour doesnt appear at 20190831 the value of  PRinlast124months starts decreasing. What is the logic behind the field PRinlast124months?

Comment: Please only use sample data in text format, do not use images..[Why not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DATEDIFF()` function to check the last 24 months e.g. :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, current_row_date, date_to_be_compared) <= 24
```

Comment: It should be based on each row (each month with previous  24 months). So count principal flag(Y) from current row to previous 24 months. Hope it make sense. Thank you for reply.